# Query - Find new and repeating users in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a visit table with user_id and visited_at columns. I would like to find how many are new and repeat customer in this month.

```
user_id      visited_at                

--------------------------------------------------------------------------

1750        2015-04-06 10:39:20
1870        2015-04-05 15:48:11
1990        2015-04-04 12:38:35
1920        2015-04-03 10:18:21
1080        2015-04-01 10:18:21
1750        2015-01-28 12:38:59
1920        2015-01-19 17:20:20
1920        2015-01-17 15:10:10
1080        2015-01-13 20:18:41
1920        2014-04-04 10:31:15
1750        2013-10-04 10:39:20
```

In January 2015, user 1750 and 1920 visited the same place so total repeated customers are 2. In April 2015, user 1750, 1920 and 1080 visited the same place so total repeated customers are 3. The output should be something like this

```
Month               New        Repeat
----------------------------------------------
October 2013        1          0
April 2014          1          0
January 2015        1          2
April 2015          2          3
```

Comment: two `april 2014` rows? how does that work?

Comment: I have tried a code but that's grouping of month and year. It just gives me total count in a particular month. I want to differentiate between new and repeat. That's where I am struggling now.

Comment: @MarcB sorry, that was a typo. I have corrected it.

Comment: so what defines a repeat user? their `updated` != `created`?

Comment: Do you want counts of users in each month or counts of visits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is to get the date of the first visit for each user using a subquery.  Then join in this information, and use `count(distinct)` to count the number of users:

```
select year(v.visited_at) as yyyy, month(visited_at) as mm,
       count(distinct user_id) as num_users,
       count(case when v.visited_at = vv.minva then user_id end) as num_new_users
from visits v join
     (select user_id, min(visited_at) as minva
      from visits t
      group by user_id
     ) vv
     on v.user_id = vv.user_id
group by year(v.visited_at), month(visited_at)
order by year(v.visited_at),  month(visited_at);
```

I note that this gives the total and new users; the repeats are the difference.

Comment: This is for month and year. Can I also do it day wise in a month or do I have to write another query? e.g. A person visited the same place on 02 April 2015 and 03 April 2015 and his first visit was in 12 April 2014. so on 12 April 2014, new would be 1 and repeat 0. For 02 April 2015, it would be new - 0 and repeat 1 and for 03 April 2015, it would be new - 0 and repeat 1.

Comment: @Chopra . . . Please ask that as a different question -- along with sample data and desired results (those really help clarify a question).

Comment: Here is the new question posted - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29498674/find-new-and-repeat-customers-datewise-in-mysql

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will work:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE updated_at >= CAST('2014-02-01' AS DATE) AND updated_at <= CAST('2014-02-28' AS DATE);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    MONTH(created_at) as _Month,
    YEAR(created_at) as _Year,
    COUNT(*) as New
FROM
    yourtable
GROUP BY 0,1
```

You can also filter results using where clause.

Comment: What is 0,1 ? is it typo? I have never heard about this thing?

Comment: It's a reference of the selected columns. You can also use GROUP BY fieldname, fieldname

Comment: I have already written this logic to group by month and year. I want to differentiate between new and repeat customer. That's where I am struggling.

Comment: @Chopra select and group by "user_id"!

Comment: I have updated the question and example. Changed the table structure. Have a look at it. It was an easy example and we were not able to count repeative customers.